# Sort data set with only one of each category id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have this data set:

```
Items Category ID
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     4
```

Now I want to sort this set so that it uses only 1 item per category, so I get Items: 1,2,4,6,3,5. As you can see items 3 & 5 are placed at the end, because there are already items with category 2 and 3

This is a MySQL data-set, so if this can work with a stored procedure/query this is better, otherwise PHP code is no problem.

I don't know how this technique is called? 
Any one?

Edit:

I know how a GROUP BY works. But remember. I am sorting a large data set, and with GROUP BY in this example Item 3 and 5 dissapear.

I want to cycle to all the categories like 1,2,3,4 and pick the first value out of it and base the order of the items on this. When there are still items the loop has to run and then place item 3 and 5 at the end.

I know my description is difficult! Sorry

Comment: Can clarify your question a bit more? As far as I can see, 3 and 5 are not placed at the end. 6 and 4 are at the end.

Comment: I want to sort on category id, but only use one item of this. So it gets sorted like: 1,2,4,6,3. It uses category  1 2 3 4 2 3.  Understand?

Comment: One option would be to convert the array into a collection implementation and do the sorting on the collection. Laravel's collections [can be installed separately](https://github.com/tightenco/collect) and would make this fairly straightforward.

Comment: It would be helpful to avoid confusion if you would just add the desired output in table format, like you did for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to give a row number based on the `CatergoryId` column. Then sort it based on row number first and then other columns.

**Query**

```
select t.`Items`, t.`CategoryID` from(
    select `Items`, `CategoryID`,
    (
        case `CategoryID` when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := `CategoryID` end 
    ) as rn 
    from `your_table_name` t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by `CategoryID`, `Items`
)t
order by t.`rn`, t.`CategoryID`;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/WOEC46319)**

Comment: Thanks. This is the best option for me! Very clever!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` to get all the `min` items first items and then, all the remaining items, e.g.:

```
SELECT MIN(Items)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY category_id

UNION

SELECT Items
FROM tablename
WHERE Items NOT IN (
   SELECT MIN(Items)
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY category_id
)
ORDER BY category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS items FROM tbl GROUP BY category_id ORDER BY item
```

after above , you can get the required result by the following way

```
$temp_arr = array();
$temp = array();
foreach($db_result as $result){
    $items = explod(',',$result);
    array_push($temp_arr,$items[0]);
    unset($items[0]);
    $temp = array_merge($temp,$items);
}

$final_array = array_merge($temp_arr,$temp);
```

Answer (score -1):

Used group by clause its give unique category item list

`select Items,Category ID from table group by Category ID`